# Cleaning trailing zeros (.00) from dates so the Group function works in a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

Using Excel 2010, I am getting a

> Cannot group that selection

error when attempting to group dates.  The date data came to me in an `.xls` file with this format: `2016-01-07 5:00 PM` in a single column.

Using Text to Columns feature, I peeled off the dates to a separate column.  The dates display correctly, however, when inserted into a Pivot Table and I attempt to group the dates, I get the referenced error.  If I reformat the data to numbers, it is not clean data.  The date `2016-01-23` converts to `42392.00`.

My thinking is these trailing `.00`s are creating unclean data fields that Excel's pivot feature cannot group.  There are thousands of lines of this data and I cannot possible convert each by hand.

I've tried removing the zeros using the decimal reduction tool and they visually disappear but when recreating a pivot table with the new formatting, the error message continues. Frustrated, I need some assistance please.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, dates are just whole numbers - as you've identified, everything after the decimal point are your hours, minutes and seconds.

Just add a helper column to trim off the extra digits. If your data starts in column `B2`, add a column `C` starting with the following formula, filled down to the bottom of the sheet: `=FLOOR(B2,0)`

This will round your data down, trimming off any hours which may not be what you're looking for. Alternatively, consider the `CEILING` or `ROUND` instead of `FLOOR` to either round them all up or to the nearest day.